# How to keep modal open if errors exists for devise?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Modal that has a devise form for authentication. If I click keep the fields clear and click on 'Sign Up', the errors do appear on the modal but the modal closes. **How do I keep the modal open if form errors exist?**

As you can see I have already tried in the script tags but this doesn't work.

`````
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Welcome! Please Log in</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, remote: true, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= f.input :email,
                            required: true,
                            autofocus: true,
                            input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
                <%= f.input :password,
                            required: true,
                            hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                            required: true,
                            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </div>
         <% end %>

            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
        <%= button_to(
        "Log Out",
        destroy_user_session_path,
        method: :delete
      ) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <% if resource.errors %>
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    <% end %>
  });
</script>````
`````

Comment: why don't you use a real `<dialog>` element with `showModal()` method ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: [I imagine that you are interested in reading the documentation, but not always diligently...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal).
Otherwise for the form use the `required` attributes, this will save you from writing unnecessary code